# Inner product proof, V is finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space with basis $B=$ {$v_{1}, v_{2},...,v_{n}$}

Prove that there is an inner product on $V$ with respect to, which $B$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I don't understand your "So, ..." sentence at all. What properties do inner products have? Have you implemented that?

Comment: oh, that is just my thought

Comment: So, I know that the standard basis with respect to inner product is the dot product, and I made some progress, how to define a inner product using different basis? How to express this?
Here are my progress, 
For any $x,y$ in $V$, $x=c_{1}v_{1}+...+c_{n}v_{n}$ and $y=d_{1}v_{1}+...+d_{n}v_{n}$ Then $\langle c_{1}v_{1}+...+c_{n}v_{n}, d_{1}v_{1}+...+d_{n}v_{n}\rangle=???$

Comment: You just retyped all the same stuff that made no sense. Please answer my question. What are the important properties that an inner product must have? Have you used these? And what do you know about $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$ in this inner product you're trying to define?

Comment: Inner product properties? em...    Positive definite. symmetric, bilinear, and ...   Oh, I just realized something

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is a basis of $V$ then for each $x,y\in V$ there exists unique tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_n) $ and $(y_1,\dots y_n)$ s.t. $x=x_1v_1+\cdots+x_nv_n$ and $y=y_1v_1+\cdots+y_nv_n$.
Then you can define $\langle x,y\rangle_B = x_1y_1+\cdots+x_ny_n$
It is easy to prove that this is a scalar product, and that $B$ is orthonormal in this scalar product.

Comment: Yes, but like how, can you say more about it?  Thank you!

Comment: How do you prove that $B$ is orthonormal? You can do the following: let $v_i$ and $v_k\in B$, you can write $v_i = 0v_1+\cdots+1v_i+\cdots0v_n$ and $v_k = 0v_1+\cdots+1v_k+\cdots0v_n$. Then $\langle v_i, v_i\rangle_b = 0*0+\cdots+1*1+\cdots 0* 0= 1$ and for $i\neq k$ $\langle v_k, v_i\rangle_b = 0*0+\cdots+1*0+\cdots 0*1+\cdots0*0= 0$

Comment: well, first prove it is orthogonal, then prove all the vectors, length is 1 ?

Comment: Just edited my comment, maybe is clear now

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much. I got it.